# Insert graphic/vector drawing from PDF into different PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, vector-graphics

I'm hitting brick walls trying to see if this is possible.

My current scenario is that we have a process (out of our control) that generates PDFs with an image logo in the top left. The image resolution is very low and looks bad. I'm trying to replace it with a vector based version of the logo and I can't seem to figure out how to do this using iTextSharp. I know that I could insert a higher resolution image, but I want a graphic/vector drawing to be there instead (scales with zoom, for the challenge, etc.)

I've tried to figure out if I can copy the PDF draw operands + content for the graphic into a new PDF but this doesn't seem easily doable.

Is there a way to just insert an SVG at a specific position and size using iTextSharp? Or some other way I can insert this vector graphic?

Comment: You talk about iTextSharp. That name was abandoned 2 years ago in favor of iText for .NET. The first SVG support was introduced in iText 7.1.2, so you'll need to upgrade to that version if you want SVG. WMF may be an alternative, since WMF files are also converted to PDF syntax. Or you could create your logo as a 1-page PDF (not a PDF with raster images!), create a `PdfImportedPage` object from that page, and then wrap that `PdfImportedPage` inside an `Image` object. That will also add the logo as a vector image.

Comment: *"I've tried to figure out if I can copy the PDF draw operands + content for the graphic into a new PDF but this doesn't seem easily doable."* - maybe not *easily* (but maybe you merely didn't know an easy way), but it definitively is *doable*. Probably you gave up too quickly here... what is your input you try to copy from? As @Bruno indicates, a *`PdfImportedPage` inside an `Image` object* probably is all you need...